Horizontal RecyclerView with two-row and different width
I'm creating this type of design using a horizontal RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager in Android.
Need like design

Current Out Put

RecyclerView Declaration Code
val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager =
            GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
binding.rvStoreTypesHome.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
binding.rvStoreTypesHome.adapter = StoreTypesAdapter(requireContext())

Adapter
class StoreTypesAdapter(val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreTypesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
var width = 0

init {
    width = context.getDeviceWidth()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding =
        StoreTypesAdapterBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val layoutParams = holder.binding.conSTAdapter.layoutParams
    layoutParams.width = if (holder.adapterPosition % 2 == 0) {
        (width / 2.5).toInt()
    } else {
        (width / 3.5).toInt()
    }
    layoutParams.height = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    holder.binding.conSTAdapter.layoutParams = layoutParams
    holder.binding.tvStoreNameSTAdapter.text = "Store Name $position"
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 10
}

inner class ViewHolder(var binding: StoreTypesAdapterBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}


Set width dynamically using device width but only showing the first
position width. 0,1,2 text is a position that I'm getting in
onBindViewHolder.


Maybe you can try overriding getItemViewType() on adapter and return view type depends on it's position.
Furthermore, creating 2 types of viewHolder then bind it.
check this post:
How to create RecyclerView with multiple view types

You should use Staggered RecyclerView. I am attaching a link for your better understanding.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-in-android-with-example/
https://medium.com/swlh/staggered-recyclerview-with-multiple-selection-in-kotlin-8eb37d5ba9e1

